# how to configure nginx to rewrite all the requests to a bootstrap php file

Tags: php, apache, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm planning to migrate from apache to nginx, however this rewritting stuff keep dragging me down. Really depressed!

When in apache `.htaccess`, I have this single line to do the right thing:

```
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

That means everything like:

```
http://example.com/a/b/c/d
```

will be rewritten to:

```
http://example.com/index.php/a/b/c/d
```

When I stepped to the nginx, I was expecting the same thing with this single line of code in the conf:

```
rewrite ^(.*) /index.php/$1     last;
```

BUT, it keeps giving me the 404 page?!

Comment: Better code formatting. Question is otherwise sensible.

Answer (score 0):

It's a single line of code indeed:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution to configure Nginx to rewrite all the requests to your Bootstrap PHP file:

```
if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite (.*) /index.php$1;
}
```